# Unable to build react native ios applozic chat implementation

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, applozic

I have installed [React native applozic chat](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-React-Native-Chat-Messaging-SDK) plugin and followed all the procedure mention in **installation** and usage section, but still I am not able to build the iOS application.
 I am getting error like

> **"include of non-modular header inside framework module 'Applozic.Applozic': 'Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALChatLauncher.h'"**

and also getting other error,

**Please check below ios debug log**

```
     While building module 'Applozic' imported from /Users/softwareDev/Sites/Dev-iOS/ios/applozic/ALChatManager.h:11:
     In file included from <module-includes>:1:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic-umbrella.h:17:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALAttachmentService.h:16:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ApplozicClient.h:9:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic.h:23:
     In file included from Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALChatLauncher.h:11:
     In file included from Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALConversationProxy.h:11:
     Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALTopicDetail.h:28:41: error: property has a previous declaration
     @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *topicId;
                                             ^
     While building module 'Applozic' imported from /Users/softwareDev/Sites/Dev-iOS/ios/applozic/ALChatManager.h:11:
     In file included from <module-includes>:1:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic-umbrella.h:16:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALAppLocalNotifications.h:11:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALMessageService.h:15:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALChannelService.h:19:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALChannelFeed.h:11:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALChannel.h:12:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALConversationProxy.h:11:
     /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALTopicDetail.h:28:41: note: property declared here
     @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *topicId;
                                             ^
     While building module 'Applozic' imported from /Users/softwareDev/Sites/Dev-iOS/ios/applozic/ALChatManager.h:11:
     In file included from <module-includes>:1:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic-umbrella.h:17:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALAttachmentService.h:16:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ApplozicClient.h:9:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic.h:23:
     In file included from Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALChatLauncher.h:11:
     In file included from Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALConversationProxy.h:11:
     Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALTopicDetail.h:29:47: error: property has a previous declaration
     @property (nonatomic,strong)  NSMutableArray *fallBackTemplateList;
                                                   ^
     While building module 'Applozic' imported from /Users/softwareDev/Sites/Dev-iOS/ios/applozic/ALChatManager.h:11:
     In file included from <module-includes>:1:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic-umbrella.h:16:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALAppLocalNotifications.h:11:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALMessageService.h:15:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALChannelService.h:19:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALChannelFeed.h:11:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALChannel.h:12:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALConversationProxy.h:11:
     /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALTopicDetail.h:29:47: note: property declared here
     @property (nonatomic,strong)  NSMutableArray *fallBackTemplateList;
                                                   ^
     While building module 'Applozic' imported from /Users/softwareDev/Sites/Dev-iOS/ios/applozic/ALChatManager.h:11:
     In file included from <module-includes>:1:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic-umbrella.h:17:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ALAttachmentService.h:16:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/ApplozicClient.h:9:
     In file included from /Users/softwareDev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HandsOn-ajtvpvdjxuhyfwfcetsvebqdrfta/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Applozic/Applozic.framework/Headers/Applozic.h:23:
     In file included from Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALChatLauncher.h:11:
     In file included from Pods/Applozic/Applozic/ALConversationProxy.h:12:
     Pods/Applozic/Applozic/DB_ConversationProxy.h:11:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'DB_ConversationProxy'
     @interface DB_ConversationProxy : NSManagedObject
```

Comment: What is your react -native version?

Comment: @AshishKanswal , I am using React native version 0.59.5

Comment: What is the xcode version you are using? You need to have xcode version 10.2 and above to be able to run this version. Also what is the Applozic pod version in your Podfile?